# WebRTC screen capture is still unsafe even if HTTPS is used

Tags: javascript, firefox, https, webrtc, mozilla

I'm trying to catch the screen and display it in the browser (**Mozilla Firefox**). For that purpose I use WebRTC and web-server.
HTML and JS are here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    screen_constraints = { 
        video: {
          mediaSource: "screen"
        }   
    };

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getUserMedia(screen_constraints, onstream, onerror);

    function onstream(stream) {

        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }

    function onerror(e) {

      console.error(e); 
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <video autoplay></video>

</body>
</html>
```

But after executing this code the error occurs and console shows:

```js
MediaStreamError { name: "SecurityError", message: "The operation is insecure.", constraint: "", stack: "" }
```

The console also shows the warning before error: `"This site uses the SHA-1 certificate; it is recommended to use certificates with the signature algorithms that use stronger hash than SHA-1."`.
I'm using HTTPS, and I've added my site to the exceptions list of my browser and allowed all permissions for it, but this error occurs constantly :(
Please, help me to resolve this problem!

Comment: What version of Firefox? Also, note that `*.domain.com` and `domain.com` are different.

Comment: @jib The version of firefox is 44.0.2. The link looks like this: https://example:444 (with https at the beginning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is because of same origin issue. Make sure the flags are set correctly in `about:config`,

- make sure `media.getusermedia.screensharing.enabled` is set true
- and the `media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains` list contains your domain name( including the `www.` if it is that way in your certs),
- and as for the `This site uses the SHA-1 certificate;...` warning, you can ignore it, it does not affect screen sharing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You made my day)
The reason was in `media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains` property, since there was not the appropriate record about my site. It's strange since I've added exceptions for it from cert file, but, anyway, now all works perfectly! Thank you)